# Origen de datos LINQ TO SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

si diseño un proyecto usando `Linq to Sql`, como puedo cambiar una vez compilado el origen de datos?
Es decir, usando la libreria `System.Data.Sqlclient`, te las ingenias para cambiar la cadena de conexión. ¿Pero usando `Linq to Sql`, que genera el `.dbml`, como se puede usar luego la aplicación en otra maquina con otra instancia de `SQLSERVER`, aunque la BBDD tenga el mismo nombre?

Comment: Siempre hay una cadena de conexion, o la creas vos o te la crea el ORM, en tu caso se guardaria en los archivos de configuracion, la base de datos seria la misma pero no el nombre de la maquina, podes guardar tu base de datos en tu carpeta raiz del programa y buscarla siempre ahi.

Comment: El hecho es que esta aplicación ha de funcionar con una base de datos ya existente, la pregunta sería de como mapear esa base de datos en la aplicación en tiempo de ejecución.